# Load file to create a dataframe in r

Tags: r

I have the file data/spatial/tissue_pos.csv and want to load it and create a dataframe object called `spatial.data` with the two columns `x`and `y` holding the *x* and *y* coordinates of the data. I am new to R and do not know how this is done. I am given some hints:

> The second-to-last and last columns in `tissue_pos.csv`
> represent the *x* and *y* coordinates respectively. You can ignore all
> other columns except the barcodes of course.
>
> There are **more entries in the file than there are spots in the expression data**, the entries are also **differently sorted**, make
> sure to adjust for this and that the rownames and colnames match once
> you've loaded the data.
>
> To find *common elements* in two sets of vectors, there's a nifty command called *intersect*.

But I am still unsure of how to do this. All help is truly appreciated!

Comment: You can use [`read.csv()`](https://rdrr.io/r/utils/read.table.html) in base R, or [`read_csv()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/readr/man/read_delim.html) from the **`readr`** package.  Use `?read.csv` or `?readr::read_csv` to see details on usage.

Comment: Hi Confused! You can also use `data.table::fread()` and select the variables you want to load: `dt <- data.table::fread("tissue_pos.csv", select = c("x", "y"))`. You can select variables by name or position. See `?data.table::fread` for additional information
`

Comment: Thank you both! I will try it :)

Comment: confused, if you don't have in your assignment clear instructions on using `read.csv`, I suspect that something else in the course material included such information. The "hints" here indicate many more steps than just `read.csv` (or similar functions) for reading it in, and are likely going to spiral this question into you asking us to do the assignment for you. We can generally help with individual and specific items, but your first stop here should be to read the rest of the course materials, or if there are none, go to the instructor to see what you are missing.